# git - recover deleted files from a prior commit

Tags: git

I accidentally deleted some files in a prior commit and would like to recover them. How can I do this?

I ran this and found exactly what I was looking for:

```
git whatchanged --diff-filter=D
```

At the time I made the commit, I should have committed the new/changed files only and ran a `reset --hard` then to recover the missing files. I have about 100 files that I need to restore.

I don't want to do a straight revert as that will also undo the changes in that commit.

Any ideas?

Comment: what operating-system do you use?

Comment: look over [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/953481/restore-a-deleted-file-in-a-git-repo). They found allready an answer to exact the same question.

Comment: Perfect, I found something that will work for me.  I wrote a nice tiny script to put together a list of files and then checkout those files.

Answer (score 1):

Check out (clone) to somewhere and do the revert there. Extract your files and delete somewhere afterwards.

Comment: Simple and straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

```
Checkout my gist solution: 
https://gist.github.com/KalemaEdgar/a88a09b8bfbf4f63dafce67b7721600c
```

Display a location summary of all deleted files.

```
$ git log --diff-filter=D --summary
commit fd87304411b93bbf7414f39251ba5e4134b27755 (HEAD)
Author: Kalema Edgar <testemail@gmail.com>
Date:   Wed May 1 14:02:36 2019 +0300

    Revert "Version 1.0.0 for app"

    This reverts commit 81585e50d2523c76f9ce7a4375e9b548895773f0.

 delete mode 100644 bootstrap.php
 delete mode 100644 composer.json
 delete mode 100644 composer.lock
```

Find the last commit that affected the path. The path from where the files were deleted

```
$ git rev-list -n 1 HEAD -- <file_path>
```

```
username@servername /htdocs/app ((fd87304...))
$ git rev-list -n 1 HEAD -- . (I am using a dot cause I am in the same directory)
fd87304411b93bbf7414f39251ba5e4134b27755
```

The commit that caused the deletion was `fd87304411b93bbf7414f39251ba5e4134b27755`.

Checkout the version at that commit to return the files back.

```
username@servername /htdocs/app ((fd87304...))
$ git checkout fd87304411b93bbf7414f39251ba5e4134b27755^ -- <filepath_to_recover>

$ git checkout fd87304411b93bbf7414f39251ba5e4134b27755^ -- .
```